# Transforming a matrix by placing its elements in the reverse order of the initial in python

Tags: python, matrix

im looking to solve the problem mentioned in the title without any specific functions that may or may not exist for this[[image: Example]]. Something along the lines of using mostly loops.

I tought about reversing each individual row using list.reverse() and then moving the rows around but im not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Seems like a possible solution. Try it out. Once you are stuck ask again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this new realization and this will not change the original Matrix

```py
Matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
newMatrix = []
for line in range(len(Matrix)):
    newMatrix.append(sorted(Matrix[line],reverse=True))

newMatrix.reverse()
print(newMatrix)
print(Matrix)
```

output:

```
[[9, 8, 7], [6, 5, 4], [3, 2, 1]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realise I could reverse the whole matrix after reversing each line.

Comment: Sorting only works for this specific input. It did not work in general.

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```py
Matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
newMatrix = []
for line in range(len(Matrix)):
    Matrix[line].reverse()
    newMatrix.append(Matrix[line])

newMatrix.reverse()
print(newMatrix)
```

output

```
[[9, 8, 7], [6, 5, 4], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: This will leave the original `Matrix` partially reversed. It seems prudent to either modify it completely inplace or not at all.

Comment: You can try using the method `sorted(list,reverse = True)`   for a temporary sort

Comment: if you want to completely change the original Matrix , use the statement `Matrix = newMatrix[ : ] ` to clone